# Get top biggest values from each column of the pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
  'first': [40, 32, 56, 12, 89],
  'second': [13, 45, 76, 19, 45],
  'third': [98, 56, 87, 12, 67]
}, index = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'])
```

I want to create a new `DataFrame` that will contain top 3 values from each column of my `data` `DataFrame`.

Here is an expected output:

```
   first  second  third
0     89      76     98
1     56      45     87
2     40      45     67
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a function to return the top three values of a series:

```
def sorted(s, num):
    tmp = s.sort_values(ascending=False)[:num]  # earlier s.order(..)
    tmp.index = range(num)
    return tmp
```

Apply it to your data set:

```
In [1]: data.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, 3))
Out[1]:
   first  second  third
0     89      76     98
1     56      45     87
2     40      45     67
```

Answer (score 3):

With numpy you can get array of top-3 values along columns like follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> col_ind = np.argsort(data.values, axis=0)[::-1,:]
>>> ind_to_take = col_ind[:3,:] + np.arange(data.shape[1])*data.shape[0]
>>> np.take(data.values.T, ind_to_take)
array([[89, 76, 98],
       [56, 45, 87],
       [40, 45, 67]], dtype=int64)
```

You can convert back to DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(_, columns = data.columns, index=data.index[:3])
       first  second  third
One       89      76     98
Two       56      45     87
Three     40      45     67
```

Comment: Note that this solution has superlinear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions (at the time of writing this), sort the DataFrame with super-linear complexity *per column*, but it can actually be done with linear time per column.

first, [`numpy.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) partitions the *k* smallest elements at the *k* first positions (unsorted otherwise). To get the *k* largest elements, we can use

```
import numpy as np

-np.partition(-v, k)[: k]
```

Combining this with dictionary comprehension, we can use:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({c: -np.partition(-data[c], 3)[: 3] for c in data.columns})
    first   second  third
0   89  76  98
1   56  45  87
2   40  45  67
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative pandas solution:

```
In [6]: N = 3

In [7]: pd.DataFrame([df[c].nlargest(N).values.tolist() for c in df.columns],
   ...:              index=df.columns,
   ...:              columns=['{}_largest'.format(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]).T
   ...:
Out[7]:
           first  second  third
1_largest     89      76     98
2_largest     56      45     87
3_largest     40      45     67
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nlargest` like

```
In [1594]: pd.DataFrame({c: data[c].nlargest(3).values for c in data})
Out[1594]:
   first  second  third
0     89      76     98
1     56      45     87
2     40      45     67
```

<sub>where</sub>

```
In [1603]: data
Out[1603]:
        first  second  third
first      40      13     98
second     32      45     56
third      56      76     87
fourth     12      19     12
fifth      89      45     67
```