# Sorting every column on a very large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorting every column of a very large pandas dataframe using a for loop. However, this process is taking very long because the dataframe has more than 1 million columns. I want this process to run much faster than it is running right now.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
top25s = []
for i in range(1, len(mylist)):
    topchoices = df.sort_values(i, ascending=False).iloc[0:25, 0].values 
    top25s.append(topchoices)
```

Here len(mylist) is 14256 but can easily go up to more than 1000000 in the future. df has a dimension of 343 rows × 14256 columns.

Thanks for all of your inputs!

Comment: If you have to sort the values for each of your 14,000 columns, it will probably take a while because of the fact that that is a lot of information for your computer to go through. When using pandas, you normally shouldn't use a for loop. Pandas probably has a better alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top biggest values from each column of the pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477190/get-top-biggest-values-from-each-column-of-the-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose using a bit of help from numpy. Which should speed things up significantly.

The following code will return a 2D numpy array with the top25 elements in each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,100)) # Generate random data

rank = df.rank(axis = 0, ascending=False)
top25s = np.extract(rank<=25, df).reshape(25, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlargest`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(25).reset_index(drop=True))
```

But I doubt this will gain you much time honestly. As commented, you just have a lot of data to go through.